# Discord Bot giving syntax error while trying to start

Tags: javascript, discord.js

my main.js file looks

```
const Discord = require('discord.js')
const client = Discord.Client()

client.login("Token")
```

I didn't use Token,as written above instead used the actual token provided to me by discord.
As I am trying run the code it's giving this error

```
/home/arnab/Desktop/my_bot/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/Client.js:41
    } catch {
            ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token {
    at createScript (vm.js:80:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:139:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:616:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:596:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/arnab/Desktop/my_bot/node_modules/discord.js/src/index.js:8:11)
```

my node js version is 8.10.0

Comment: code should be `} catch(e) {` - only later versions of node allow the syntax you're using - oops, not you, but that node module .. current version is 14.13 or 12.18.4LTS ... upgrade node

Comment: Discord.JS Requires A Minimum Node Version Of 12.0

Answer (score 0):

try using

```html
const Discord = require('discord.js')
const client = new Discord.Client()

client.login("Token")
```

Answer (score 0):

You are probably using the wrong version of Node.js. Try `node —-version`. If it‘s lower than 12 you need to update it. To do this you type `npm cache clean -f` then `npm install n -g` and then `n stable`. If `node —-version` still says the old version you need to type `PATH=$PATH` into the terminal. Where I know it from? I had the problem too and I found out about the required node version in the discord.js v12 documentation.